# Wrong access to struct elements in Perl

Tags: perl, pack, crc16, uint16

I am writing a Perl script capable of loading a binary RAW file (.bin file extension), calculate the CRC-16 (unsigned short, 16bits ~ 2 bytes), and store this CRC in a file trailer, using the following commands:

```
my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new( type => 'crc16' );  #OK :)
open my $FH, '<:raw', $inFile or die $!;        #OK :)
$ctx->addfile(*$FH);                            #OK :)
print ("$inFile CRC16 value = 0x");             #OK :)
my $digest = $ctx->hexdigest;                   #OK :)
print $digest, "\n";                            #OK :)
print WRITEHANDLE pack("n*", $digest);          #NOT OK :(
```

Last command raises a warning, and more the CRC is not stored in the correct way

[image]

and in the binary output last 2 bytes are not once calculated/expected

[image]

It is clear that I am not using properly the pack method for storing the value, but from the pack() MAN

[image]

What is the correct Template for pack() in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the warning, you have the string `6c5b`, but `pack 'n'` expects a number. `$ctx->digest` produces that number.

```perl
print WRITEHANDLE pack 'n', $ctx->digest;
```

That said, with the hex representation of the digest, you can use `pack 'H*'` (as long as it's left-padded with zeroes).

```perl
print WRITEHANDLE pack 'H*', $ctx->hexdigest;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was considering digest value `6C5B` as numeric and not a string.
Your suggestion works perfectly!

Comment: Hex is a *text* representation of a number